# Solve $e^y\sin{2x}dx+\cos (e^{2y}-y)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$$e^y\sin{2x}dx+\cos (e^{2y}-y)dy=0$$

I divided equation by $e^y \cos x$ and now don't know how to proceed.

Comment: you can separate the variables like $e^{-y}\letft(\cos(e^{2y} - y)}\right),\ dy + \sin 2x \, dx = 0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have divided by $e^y$ so that x and y would be separated from each other.

$-\sin{2x}dx = \frac{\cos{(e^{2y} - y)}}{e^y}dy$

After that, you could take $\sin{2x}dx$ to other side and integrate both sides.

Although I doubt that this equation has analytical answer.

Comment: So i have to vanish e^y from the equation right?

Comment: You can't vanish it.